# Can spinning wheels while stuck in the snow damage a CVT?

Tags: cvt-transmission

I pulled over today and the front of my car went into the snow and got stuck. I managed to free myself by shifting into reverse and flooring it for about 30-45 seconds.

Could I have damaged my CVT transmission by doing this? The car in question is a Nissan Maxima.

Also, how can doing something like this potentially damage a CVT transmission? Is the overheating that's the primary reason for why the damage occurs, or is there something else at play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flooring in reverse wouldn't make your transmission damaged otherwise when you driving forward you will change your transmission every day.
Just check your oil condition in your transmission.

Comment: I don't understand. Why wouldn't flooring it in reverse while my car is stuck damage the transmission?

Comment: If you got stuck but one of your drive tires still spinning you wouldn't worry, because the transmission just revs at a limited high speed (reverse final gear is almost like 1st gear), It didn't give any load to the transmission (free-wheeling).

Comment: Okay, I understand. Does the same concept apply to a Nissan CVT?

Comment: Nissan CVT tends to broke after exceeding 100K miles, flooring it under 1minute is not making any difference at all. Unless your CVT is on the edge of failure. CVT on Nissan tends to get hotter than any other CVT while driving because of bad design I guess. The belts inside this CVT are likely to be culprits for making it hotter and have not an adequate cooling system is the problem on the first hand.